# Images hyperlink and outline at IE. I don't want remove outline at all

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, outline

I have hyperlink with image and text. I've made stronger standard focus. I don't want outline, when I just click hyperlink, so I use `a:active { outline : none }`. When I click some text at hyperlink everything is fine, unfortunately when I clik image I have outline. It seems that `a:active { outline : none }` doesn't work when I click image at hyperlink. This problem I have only at `IE`. Firefox, Chrome and Opera are OK. Is there any way to fix this? I'll be appreciated for any help.

This is my example code:

```
<style type="text/css">
a:focus { 
    outline : 3px solid black;
}
a:active { 
    outline : none;
}
</style>
<a href="index.html" title="Hyperlink"><img src="image.jpg" alt=" " width="160" height="160" /> Some text </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset this by simply resetting the outline on any `img` element within the `a` element. IE also applies a border around images within `a` elements by default, which you may not want either:

```css
a img {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately outline is still there. I have outline when I click image at hyperlink. I want remove outline only in this case. This bad efect I have only at IE. I think that problem is bigger :) but thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems to be because IE applies `:focus`, not `:active` when clicked. What you can do is separate your text into a `span` and only apply your `:focus` outline on the `span` element using `a:focus span { ... }`.

Comment: I did like this:

<style type="text/css">

a:focus span { 
outline: 3px solid black;
}

a:active span { 
 outline: none;
}

</style>

<a href="index.html" title="Hyperlink"><img src="image.jpg" alt=" " width="160" height="160" /><span> Some text </span></a>

And I still have outline around text when I click image or text at hyperlink :(

Comment: IE doesn't properly apply `:active` to links. It applies `:focus`. IE is applying the 3px outline and nothing more.